# Convolution with BigQuery Window functions?

Tags: google-bigquery

Is this something I can do? I'm looking to try and cross-correlate two time series.

I think the window function should do it, but not 100% sure how to construct it in SQL.

Comment: You need to provide much more details as not all are familiar with convolution.

Comment: I think it's difficult to describe convolution here, but here is a good description: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation

Comment: did you tried adapting existing solutions http://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/23301348/What-is-the-best-way-to-compute-autocorrelation.html

Answer (score 1):

Just as an idea to play with (more suited for comments but easier to present in answer):

```
SELECT
  CORR(a, b) AS correlation,
  CORR(a, b1) AS cross_correlation_lag_1,
  CORR(a, b2) AS cross_correlation_lag_2,
  CORR(a, b3) AS cross_correlation_lag_3,
  CORR(a, b4) AS cross_correlation_lag_4,
  CORR(a, b5) AS cross_correlation_lag_5
FROM (
  SELECT 
    a.ts AS ts, 
    a.val AS a, 
    b.val AS b,
    LEAD(b.val, 1) OVER(ORDER BY b.ts) AS b1,
    LEAD(b.val, 2) OVER(ORDER BY b.ts) AS b2,
    LEAD(b.val, 3) OVER(ORDER BY b.ts) AS b3,
    LEAD(b.val, 4) OVER(ORDER BY b.ts) AS b4,
    LEAD(b.val, 5) OVER(ORDER BY b.ts) AS b5
  FROM time_series1 AS a
  JOIN time_series2 AS b
  ON a.ts = b.ts
)
```